# How to use IssuedToken in a client with a WCF Service Reference

Tags: wcf, webservice-client, service-reference, federation, thinktecture-ident-model

I have a WinForms app with a Service Reference generated from a WCF service that uses  WS2007FederationHttpBinding.  I can't understand why the following is not working.

My WinForms app is calling a WCF service that is using Thinktecture.IdentityServer, set up to handle BearerKey type tokens.

From my client I simply acquire a valid access token, and make this call:

```
    private static void CallServiceReference(SecurityToken token)
    {
        ServiceReference1.ClaimsServiceContractClient svcRef = new ServiceReference1.ClaimsServiceContractClient();

        svcRef.ChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        svcRef.ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
        var claims = svcRef.GetClaims(); 
    }
```

Here is the winforms client app.config for the service reference:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
              <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                      <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_ClaimsServiceContract">
                              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                                      <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey">
                                              <issuer address="https://identity.MyCo.com/issue/wsfed" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                                                      bindingConfiguration="https://identity.MyCo.com/issue/wstrust/mixed/username" />
                                              <issuerMetadata address="https://identity.MyCo.com/issue/wstrust/mex" />
                                              <tokenRequestParameters>
                                                      <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                                              <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                                                              <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                                              <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                                      </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                                              </tokenRequestParameters>
                                      </message>
                              </security>
                      </binding>
              </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
              <ws2007HttpBinding>
                      <binding name="https://identity.MyCo.com/issue/wstrust/mixed/username">
                              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                                      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                                      <message clientCredentialType="IssuedToken" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                              </security>
                      </binding>
              </ws2007HttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
              <endpoint address="https://roadie/WebTest/service.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_ClaimsServiceContract"
                      contract="ServiceReference1.ClaimsServiceContract" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_ClaimsServiceContract" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I try and execute the service call (svcRef.GetClaims()) I get this error:

> "The address of the security token issuer is not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified in the binding for target 'https://identity.MyCo.com/issue/wsfed' or the local issuer address must be configured in the credentials."

This error is lame, and confusing, seems how there is an issuer specified in the config!

Lastly, I know the WCF service and Identity service are valid because this all works fine using a custom ChannelFactory, also using this exact same method to apply the token:

`var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);`

But my requirement is to use the generated ServiceReference. :(

Answer (score 3):

You should use the created channel like this:

```
private static void CallServiceReference(SecurityToken token)
{
    ServiceReference1.ClaimsServiceContractClient svcRef = 
        new ServiceReference1.ClaimsServiceContractClient();

    svcRef.ChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    var svcChannel = svcRef.ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
    var claims = svcChannel.GetClaims();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can use the generated proxy from the service reference is if you configure your client to automatically request a token and set the appropriate ClientCredentials property on the proxy instance you create before making the service call.

We are using an issued token that we keep around cached on the client in a project I work on, but then we must use the channel factory CreateChannelWithIssuedToken just as you describe.

BTW, this is when using WIF in .NET 4.0. Maybe there are other options if running on .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't have the referenced client stub DLL, then you can use reflection to dynamically load and invoke it.
Here is a reflection version to create the client with issued token:

```
//Our goal is to get a client obj from reflection
//var obj = client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);

double value1 = 2;
double value2 = 3;
//this line needs to be changed to be created from reflection if needed
CalculatorClient cc = new CalculatorClient("WS2007FederationHttpBinding_ICalculator"); var pi = cc.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelFactory"); //proprety 
var factoryObj = pi.GetValue(cc);
var mi = factoryObj.GetType().GetMethod("CreateChannelWithIssuedToken", new Type[] { typeof(SecurityToken)}); //method info
var clientObj = mi.Invoke(factoryObj, new object[] { token });
mi = clientObj.GetType().GetMethod("Add"); //another method info
var result = mi.Invoke(clientObj, new Object[] { 2, 3 });
Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, Convert.ToDouble(result));
```